# Apply Reduce on matrix

Tags: r, reduce

I am trying to apply the `Reduce` function with `|` (`OR`)  and `accumulate = TRUE` on the columns of a matrix.

Example input:

```
m <- matrix(c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1), nrow = 3)

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    0    0
[2,]    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    1
```

The result should be

```
m2 <- matrix(c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1), nrow = 3)

      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    1
[2,]    0    1    1
[3,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: Tried it out, it works, thank you

Comment: Please do not infer solutions from the structure of the matrix. I am interested in a general solution for a cumulative OR.